# JavaScript function not found in JSP

Tags: javascript

I have a few JSP pages, that include some JavaScript(jquery, jquery mobile and some javascript functions that I wrote).

When loading the pages and try to run my functions, I get in Firebug an error, that the function was not found. I have looked into the page source, and the function is there.

All the other jquery mobile functions work.

The only way to make my script work is to make a forced refresh(ctrl+f5).

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

It seems that a simple refresh would also work.

**Here is the source code of the page:**

http://pastebin.com/6sJnfPDQ

Comment: could you paste the (relevant) source code here, please? I.e. the html the browser receives.

Comment: @Bergi I edited the question, it's a link to the code.

Comment: can you also paste the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

make sure all of your js files are being loaded properly.

also make sure that your js files are being loaded in the proper order.

make sure that, where necessary, you're wrapping your JS in a document ready function of some type

also, I recommend that you add the `type` attribute to your script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The function is in document.ready and my javascript function shows up in the source(and it is between the two javascript tags). The written order is this: jquery, jquery mobile and my function.

Comment: is this live somewhere you can paste a link to?

Comment: @Dragos for starters, also try adding type attributes to your script tags as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I have retagged your question to remove "Java" and "JSP", as this is irrelevant (server vs browser).

Once your JSP is rendered in the browser, please do look in the page source and see what happened to your  tags.

Comment: My javascript function shows up in the source(and it is between the two javascript tags).

Comment: And this is the function that firebug is reporting as missing? Please check for obvious things like typos.

Comment: That is the function. There is no typo. Once I press Ctrl+F5, everything works great. Do you need some code?

Comment: Does cleaning browsing cache help? Did you try it in Chrome? As for the code - if you could make a small enough snippet that will reproduce the problem - sure!

Comment: It is not about the cache, since I get the same problem on the Android emulator(I cannot make a forced refresh there, though). And I think I can not give you enough code to reproduce the problem...

Comment: To reload the js file everytime the page loads,  append a random number to the end of the js file name for ex. Myfile.js?Xx=somerandomnumber.  With this trick the browser will think that its a new file and loads it fresh rather than from cache.

Comment: @Dragos sorry for the delay - pastebin is blocked where I work. Looking at this at home I cannot see any issues with the code, Firebug is perfectly happy. Am I missing something?